# How to do null-conditional using Option.map? And how can F# get the property of an null object? Bug?

Tags: f#

The following code returns `Some "Test"` stead of `None`. Basically, I'm trying to implement the C# code of `cObj?.B.A.P`.

```
// Setup
[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type A() =
    member x.P = "Test"

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type B(a:A) =
    member x.A = a

[<AllowNullLiteral>]
type C(b:B) =
    member x.B = b

// Test
let aObj: A = null
let cObj = new C(new B(aObj))

let r = 
    cObj |> Option.ofObj
    |> Option.map(fun c -> c.B)
    |> Option.map(fun b -> b.A) 
    |> Option.map(fun a -> a.P) // Expect return None since a is null
                                // printfn "%A" a; will print <null>.
                                // How can F# got property of null object?

r
```

It seems F# doesn't treat `null` as `None` in the Option.map. Is there a simple fix to make it return None as soon as a `null` is found?

Comment: F# optimizes certain member invocations and replaces them with their return value, because - without `AllowNullLiteral` - it does not expect them to fail. Try to compile with `--optimize-`, to get the NullReferenceException instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F#, unlike C#, tries to be explicit everywhere. In the long run this leads to more maintainable and correct programs.

In particular, `null` has absolutely nothing to do with `Option`. `null` is not the same as `None`. `None` is a value of type `Option`, while `null` is this very vague concept - a value that can be of any type.

If you would like to return `None` when the argument is `null` and `Some` otherwise, what you need is `Option.bind`, not `Option.map`. `Option.bind` takes a function that takes a value (extracted from a previous `Option`) and returns another `Option`. Something like this:

```
let maybeC = Option.ofObj cObj
let maybeB = maybeC |> Option.bind (c -> Option.ofObj c.B)
let maybeA = maybeB |> Option.bind (b -> Option.ofObj b.A)
let maybeP = maybeA |> Option.bind (a -> Option.ofObj a.P)
```

Or in one go:

```
let maybeP = 
    Option.ofObj cObj
    |> Option.bind (c -> Option.ofObj c.B)
    |> Option.bind (b -> Option.ofObj b.A)
    |> Option.bind (a -> Option.ofObj a.P)
```

If you do this sort of thing very frequently, you can combine `Option.bind` and `Option.ofObj` calls and encode that as a separate function:

```
let maybeNull f = Option.bind (x -> Option.ofObj (f x))

let maybeP =
    Option.ofObj cObj
    |> maybeNull (c -> c.B)
    |> maybeNull (b -> b.A)
    |> maybeNull (a -> a.P)
```

However, if you find yourself buried in `null`s like that, I would suggest that perhaps your domain design is not thought through very well. Nulls are not a good modeling tool, they should be avoided as much as possible. I encourage you to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to Option.map is a function `'T -> 'U`.  Its parameter is of type `'T`, not `'T option`.  So, in your last lambda `fun a -> a.P`, a null argument denotes a null of type `A`, not a null of type `A option`.

Because the member `P` of type `A` just returns the string "Test," the call succeeds and returns even though the receiver is null.  If you try to use the self identifier in the body of `P`, you will instead get a null reference exception.